# Can Dart streams save data?

Tags: asynchronous, stream, dart

It is not clear to me whether the the single subscriber streams in Dart actually save data they receive. If they do, is there a way to disable this, since this seems like a major memory leak?

With the [new](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/beyond-async/#await-for) `async*` functions in Dart, do the streams produced by these store data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code-doc on the StreamController constructor says

> - The controller will buffer all incoming events until the subscriber is
> - registered.

To avoid queued events you can use a broadcast stream

```dart
new StreamController.broadcast(...);
```

or pause the subscription

```dart
StreamSubscription sub;
sub = s.listen((e) {
  sub.pause();
  // process event
  sub.resume();
});
```

A stream created by `async*` behaves the same

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Stream<int> a() async* {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
    print('yield $i');
    yield i;
  }
}

main() {

  a().listen((e) async {
    await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    print(e);
  });

  StreamSubscription sub;
  sub = a().listen((e) async {
    sub.pause();
    await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    print(e);
    sub.resume();
  });
}
```

try at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/1c1273228c8ac6c0a5a1)

The first example prints

```
yield 1
yield 2
yield 3
yield 4
yield 5
yield 6
yield 7
yield 8
yield 9
yield 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

the second example (with `pause`) prints

```
yield 1
yield 2
yield 3
1
2
yield 4
3
yield 5
4
yield 6
5
yield 7
6
yield 8
7
yield 9
8
yield 10
9
10
```

Comment: Clarify me: does `async*` / `yield` produce a broadcast stream or a single subscription stream?

Comment: A single subscription stream as far as I know, but you can check with `a().isBroadcast`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried: `isBroadcast` returns `false` for an `async*` function, so it is a single subscription stream.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a `Future` when referring to a *single subscriber stream*.

As far as I understand the new keywords don't change the actual behaviour. The `async`/`async*` will respectively create a `Future`/`Stream` which will buffer the data naturally until they are actually *delivered*. For example you can do both:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Future single() async {
  return 42; 
}

main() async {
  int r = await single();
  print('ok: $r');

  single().then((int val) {
    print('val $val');
  });
}
```

So in the end I'd say that they behave the same, you just express what you are doing in a different way. Thus the Stream will take data only if there are listeners. And then the data will be delivered *as usual*.

A quote from their website: *One can implement streams manually using Stream and allied classes. Asynchronous generator functions are sugar for implementing such streams*

Comment: I am actually talking about the Streams produced by `async*` functions, do these delete data that has been delivered to a subscriber?

Comment: As i explained in my post, they don't differ from regular `Stream` objects thus they have the same behaviour. If there are no subscribers, data will not be buffered, and if they have, the data will be buffered until delivered to all subscribes, but after that the data is not in the buffer of the stream anymore. If you don't want this, use a `sync` Stream (See StreamController constructor and set `sync` to `true`).